# Dojo: Get displayed items from an DojoX Grid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

Is there any way to get all displayed items from an dojox.grid?

We have an Filter with querys, now we need all items displayed in the moment. To get all selected items is no problem with:

```
    var items   = grid.selection.getSelected();
```

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work for me using Chrome (with Dojo 1.6.1):

```
for (i = 0; i < grid.rowCount; i++)
{ 
  var obj = grid.getItem(i);
  // optionally, add it to the selection:
  // grid.selection.addToSelection(obj);
}
```